# Why does it print out 0?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

Why is the answer 0 and not 1? I know it has something to do with the boolean sentence, but I can't figure out how it works. From my understanding, the while loop stops when i and j are both equal to 1.

```
public void random(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 2;
    int k = 0;
    boolean keepGoing;
    keepGoing = i<j;
    while (keepGoing && k<2) {
        i++;
        j--;
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

prints out 0

Comment: Debug / step through your code and it will be clear what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably saying that because you think the `keepGoing` variable will stop the loop...
Well the `keepGoing` variable won't change at all! You instantiated your variable with this:

```
boolean keepGoing;
keepGoing = i<j;
```

This expression will look at the values of `i` and `j` **at that moment in the code**, replace these variables with their values (respectively 0 and 2 at that moment), and just process the comparison. As `i` is less than `j` **at that moment in the code** it will return true and set `keepGoing` to true. After that, `keepGoing` won't change itself each time `i` or `j` changes. That is not how it works. The value of `keepGoing` will only change if you set another value in it! **In general, a variable will only change if there is an explicit line (or method) encountered that tells it to change.** So if in your case you want `keepGoing` to change each time you change `i` or `j`, you'll have to explicitely recalculate `keepGoing` each time that happens. In your case this will be at the end of your `while` block:

```
    while (keepGoing && k<2) {
        i++;
        j--;
        k++;
        keepGoing = i<j;  //explicitely recalculate value of keepGoing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are decreasing the integer j and increasing the integer k.

The while steps look like:

1. i = 0, j = 2, k = 0
2. i = 1, j = 1, k = 1
3. i = 2, j = 0, k = 2